# Does not take me to the component (react-router, link)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a problem with react-router.

My application displays the list of recipes. In the formulator, you enter your preferences (diet, calories, allergy), the next information is sent to the api, next the list of recipes is display. I want to show the name of the dish, a photo and a button showing more, which would move me to a specific page of a given meal.

This component is responsible for rendering the recipe list

```
class ListRecipes extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    const recipe = data
      ? data.hits.map((recipe, i) => {
          return <ItemRecipe recipe={recipe} key={i} />;
        })
      : null;

    return <ul>{recipe}</ul>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: state.data
  };
};

ListRecipes = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(ListRecipes);

export default ListRecipes;
```

This component is responsible for rendering a single recipe

```
const ItemRecipe = ({ recipe }) => {
  const { label, image } = recipe.recipe;
  return (
    <li>
      <p> {label} </p>
      <img src={image} alt="food" />


      <Link to={`/meals/${label}`} >
        <p>More information</p>
      </Link >
    </li>
  );
}
```

My router looks like this

```
export default (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Main} />
      <Route path="/form" component={FormPage} />
      <Route path="/meals" component={ListRecipes} />
      <Route path="/meals/:name" component={props => <DetailsRecipe {...props} />} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

After clicking on a recipe, the address of the url changes, but it does not transfer me anywhere. (`http://localhost:3000/meals`  click button `http://localhost:3000/meals/Shrimp,%20Lemon,%20And%20Parsley%20Pasta`)

why after clicking on

```
<Link to={`/meals/${label}`} >
    <p>More information</p>
</Link >
```

does not take me to the component `DetailsRecipe`.

Comment: Where are your `Link` components rendered? You need to make sure that they are inside of the same `BrowserRouter` as the `Route` components or it will not work properly. `/meals` will also match `/meals/Shrimp`, so you could move the `/meals/:name` route above the `/meals` route, or give the `/meals` route the `exact` prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in switch tag so the first match is rendered. First match is for `<Route path="/meals" component={ListRecipes} />` so it will be rendered. Try to add param exact to this route [route doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `withRouter` HOC with ItemRecipe since it doesn't receive the Router props

```
const ItemRecipe = ({ recipe }) => {
  const { label, image } = recipe.recipe;
  return (
    <li>
      <p> {label} </p>
      <img src={image} alt="food" />


      <Link to={`/meals/${label}`} >
        <p>More information</p>
      </Link >
    </li>
  );
}

export default withRouter(ItemRecipe);
```

Also you should encode your URL params before using with with link using `enocdeURIComponent` and decode it in `DetailsRecipe` using `decodeURIComponent`

```
<Link to={`/meals/${encodeURIComponenent(label)}`} >
```